# CSS vertical stretch problem

Tags: css

There is probably a very easy solution for this, however, I'm new to CSS based layout, and any help with this would be appreciated.

I can't control the height for the main body div (that has the image) and it stretches so far down.  Why is that?  The global-inner div seems to be working fine.  Can anyone help?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div id="global-wrap">
    <div id="global-inner" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(145, 148, 138);" >
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body
{
    background: url("/images/damask-back.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 #423624;
    font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 50%;
}
#global-wrap 
{
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 925px;*/
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
#global-inner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #857A6B;
    border: 2px solid #61533F;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 898px;
    height: 298px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You have `#global-inner { ... }` in your style sheet. Why are you using the style attribute?

Comment: That doesnt make a difference if I take out the style attribute w/in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the inline styles you have on the `global-inner`, it appears to work with them removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/adhKG/

Comment: What do you mean? which inline styles on what wrapping div??

Comment: Sorry I mis-spoke the inline styles on the div inside the wrapper. I also closed the div tags just to make sure, the parent div then wraps the child div snugly. Unless I'm not-understanding the question? Check out the example.

Comment: Ahh ok I just saw your example let me give this a shot

Comment: I got the same result, I removed the other inner div tags (not-shown) and works fine.  1 inner div tag had a menu control.  I will try to add each one back to det the problem and report it.

Comment: The other stylesheet that the menu was using had its height attribute set large, I just commented it.     .SimpleEntertainmentMenu ul.AspNet-Menu /* Tier 1 */
{
    width: 84em;
    /*height:370em;*/
}